# Can I create alert on ora-20118 from Enterprise Manager?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, alerts, oracle-enterprise-manager

Can I create an alert on a user-defined `ORA-` error?

I want EM to notify me when the following error happens:

```
begin
raise_application_error(-20118, 'myerror');
end;
/
```

Comment: Does the error appear in the alert log?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: Can you make it write to the alert log? Or make it write to a file? It's relatively trivial using Metric Extensions if you can do that.

Comment: Look up DBMS_SYSTEM.KSDWRT

Comment: @AndrewBrennan you are absolutely right. This is the tool what I need.

Comment: begin
  dbms_system.ksdwrt(2,'ORA-20118: Myerror');
  raise_application_error(-20118, 'myerror');  
end;

Comment: Great. So now you've two options - alter the regex in your existing monitoring to include this error code, or write a Metric Extension to check the alert log for the code.

Comment: After that I have set in "Metric and Policy Settings"   metric "Generic Alert Log Error".
Thank you.

Comment: Cheers, I've made that an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `DBMS_SYSTEM.KSDWRT` to write the error to the alert log when you catch the relevant exception.

Then you can configure Enterprise Manager to alert on that error code. You've two options here:

1. Modify the regex for the existing error log analysis to cover this error code. This would be much easier, but might be a little inflexible.
2. Write a Metric Extension to check the alert log for this error. This would be a lot more difficult, but would allow you to create customised error messages and responses to this specific error.